# Why do these 2 approaches to applying mixed models yield different results?

Tags: r, mixed-model

I'm re-analyzing a colleague's data. The data and R code [are here](https://gist.github.com/1409791).

It's a 2x2x2x2x3 completely within-Ss design. One of the predictor variables, `cue`, is a two-level variable that when collapsed to a difference score reflects a theory-pertinent value. She previously collapsed `cue` to a difference score within each subject and condition, then computed an ANOVA, yielding an MSE that she could then use for planned comparisons of each condition's mean difference score against zero. You'll have to trust me that she wasn't fishing and did indeed have good theoretical basis for doing all 24 tests.

I thought I'd see if there was any difference when instead using mixed effects models to represent the data. As shown in the code, I took two approaches:

Method 1 - Model the data as a 2x2x2x2x3 design, obtain *a posteriori* samples from this model, compute the `cue` difference score for each condition within each sample, compute the 95% prediction interval for the cue difference score within each condition.

Method 2 - Collapse `cue` to a difference score within each subject and condition, model the data as a 2x2x2x3 design, obtain *a posteriori* samples from this model, compute the 95% prediction interval for the cue difference score within each condition.

It appears that method 1 yields broader prediction intervals than method 2 with the consequence that if one uses overlap with zero as a criterion for "significance", only 25% of the cuing scores are "significant" under method 1 while 75% of cuing scores are "significant" under method 2. Noteably, the patterns of significance obtained by method 2 are more akin to the original ANOVA-based results than are the patterns obtained by method 1.

Any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not surprising to see such a difference with lmer or lme. A simple model with a random intercept (e.g., (1|id) in your case) sometimes may fail to fully capture the random effects. To see why this happens, let me use a much simpler dataset than yours to demonstrate the subtle difference. With the data 'dat' from the [thread](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mixed-models/2011q2/006090.html) which I copy to here:

```
dat <- structure(list(sex = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L,
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L,
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("f",
"m"), class = "factor"), prevalence = c(0, 0.375, 0.133333333333333,
0.176470588235294, 0.1875, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0.5, 0.6, 0.333333333333333,
0.5, 0, 0.333333333333333, 0, 0.5, 0, 0.625, 0.333333333333333,
0.5, 0, 0.333333333333333, 0.153846153846154, 0.222222222222222,
0.5, 1, 0.5, 0, 0.277777777777778, 0.125, 0, 0, 0.428571428571429,
0.451612903225806, 0.362068965517241), tripsite = structure(c(1L,
1L, 4L, 4L, 14L, 14L, 5L, 5L, 8L, 8L, 15L, 15L, 6L, 6L, 9L, 9L,
11L, 11L, 16L, 16L, 2L, 2L, 7L, 7L, 10L, 10L, 13L, 13L, 17L,
17L, 3L, 3L, 12L, 12L, 18L, 18L), .Label = c("1.2", "4.2", "5.2",
"1.3", "2.3", "3.3", "4.3", "2.4", "3.4", "4.4", "3.5", "5.5",
"4.6", "1.9", "2.9", "3.9", "4.9", "5.9"), class = "factor")), .Names =
c("sex","prevalence", "tripsite"), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 9L,
10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L,
27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 38L, 39L, 40L,
41L, 42L, 43L, 45L, 46L), class = "data.frame")
```

a paired t-test (or a special case of one-way within-subject/repeated-measures ANOVA) would be like your Method 2:

```
t0 <- with(dat,t.test(prevalence[sex=="f"],prevalence[sex=="m"],paired=TRUE,var.equal=TRUE))
(fstat0 <- t0$statistic^2)         #0.789627
```

Its lme version corresponding to your Method 1 would be:

```
a1 <- anova(lme(prevalence~sex,random=~1|tripsite,data=dat,method="REML"))
(fstat1 <- a1[["F-value"]][2])   # 0.8056624
```

Same thing for the lmer counterpart:

```
a2 <- anova(lmer(prevalence~sex+(1|tripsite), data=dat))
(fstat2 <- a2[["F value"]][2])  # 0.8056624
```

Although the difference with this simple example is tiny, but it shows that the paired t-test has a much stronger assumption about the two levels ("f" and "m") of the factor ("sex"), that the two levels are correlated, and such assumption is absent in the above lme/lmer model. Such an assumption difference also exists between the two methods in your case.

To reconcile the difference, we can continue modeling 'dat' with a random slope (or symmetrical matrix or even compound symmetry) in lme/lmer:

```
a3 <- anova(lme(prevalence~sex,random=~sex-1|tripsite,data=dat,method="REML"))
(fstat3 <- a3[["F-value"]][2]) # 0.789627

a31 <- anova(lme(prevalence~sex,random=list(tripsite=pdCompSymm(~sex-1)),data=dat,method="REML")))
(fstat31 <- a31[["F-value"]][2]) # 0.789627

a4 <- anova(lmer(prevalence~sex+(sex-1|tripsite), data=dat))
(fstat4 <- a4[["F value"]][2]) # 0.789627
```

However, with multiple factors in your case, multiple random slopes (or other random-effects structure specifications) may become unwieldy with lme/lmer if not impossible.

Comment: Good call. I see now that collapsing to cue to a difference score prior to analysis is equivalent to permitting cue effect to vary by participant.